# How to place drawable to the right of screen where as text is left?

Tags: android

How to place drawable to the right of screen where as text is left in a radio button style as given in the image. How to achieve this task?

[image: This is my requirment]

How will I achieve the task given in the image? Issues are dynamic. They can change

Comment: Use drawableleft and drawableright in your XML to set image left and right accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this code to achieve what you want. It's one row, so you could easily add it into a RecyclerView, or just hard code it if the issues are known beforehand.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Issue 1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```